# How to return data from a BackgroundWorker in c++?

Tags: c++-cli, backgroundworker

I've got a `BackgroundWorker` continually reading data from a USB device.  I want to parse that data, then feed it back to my main GUI thread to update a plot and save it to a file.

I suspect the way to do this is using `ReportProgress`, but I'm not sure how to pass an `object` as required.

Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Datapacket
{
    public:
        int Val1;
        double Val2;
}

backgroundWorker_DoWork(Object^  sender,DoWorkEventArgs^  e) 
{
    // readUSB
    .........

    // create Datapacket with values from usb stream:
    Datapacket dp;
    dp.Val1 = 5;
    dp.Val2 = 34.6;

    backgroundWorker->ReportProgress(0, dp); // this bit fails to compile
}

backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(Object^  sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e)
{
    Datapacket dp = e.dp ??????

    // update gui, etc
    textBox_Data->Text = dp.Val1.ToString();
}
```

I usually use c#, so diving into this in C++ is a minor headache as it is!

Comment: You cannot pass an object of an unmanaged class, it does not inherit from System::Object.  It is also destroyed by the time your event handler runs, dangling pointers are major bug generators.  There is no conceivable reason to avoid declaring *Datapacket* as a `ref class` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're *near*. `Datapacket` is **not** a .NET reference type (class) and I'd assume you do not want to dispose it when it's out of scope. Change it to `ref class` and just add `^` in your `backgroundWorker_DoWork` (and change `.` with `->` where appropriate):

```
backgroundWorker_DoWork(Object^  sender,DoWorkEventArgs^  e) 
{
    Datapacket^ dp = gcnew Datapacket();
    dp->Val1 = 5;
    dp->Val2 = 34.6;

    backgroundWorker->ReportProgress(0, dp);
}
```

In your event handler you just need to cast `UserState` property to original type (and change `.` with `->` where appropriate):

```
backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(Object^  sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs^  e)
{
    Datapacket^ dp = dynamic_cast<Datapacket^>(e->UserState);

    // update gui, etc
    textBox_Data->Text = dp->Val1.ToString();
}
```

Do not forget to set `WorkerReportsProgress` to `true`.

Comment: Ignore the following - I had my class defined in the wrong place - Thanks for your help.  <ignore>So close!!  However when I try and compile, I get an error "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Datapacket'" when I try and instantiate it.</ignore>